# How to speed up Dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I am binding a gridview on a Dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged event, but I find this process to be too slow. It is taking 50-60 seconds to populate, while the amount of data i'm displaying is not bulky. (max 40 rows).
How to speed up selectedindexchanged performance?

Comment: To attract more answers, you should add a tag corresponding to the language or tools you are using. You can do that by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11718392/edit) and adding tags at the bottom of the edit page.

Comment: Without seeing code, it's very difficult to say - but 50-60 seconds to populate 40 rows of a GridView sounds extreme. Are you sure there is not major SQL query performance issue?

Comment: 1. What kind of data are you displaying; is it relational data? 2. Are there any custom processes occurring during data binding? 3. Is there an excess number of SQL calls happening?

Comment: I am simply using databind method in selectedindexchanged event using dataadapter and dataset to bind the gridview. This is very simple. I dont know why it is so slow. 
The dropdown is in a TabPanel.

Comment: @Hitesh - first you have to work out which part of your code is slow (time it!) - data access (SQL/dataadapter), data creation (dataadapter to actual c# classes and objects) or data visualization (setting gridview to the retrieved data)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding the grid view every time depend upon selectedIndex?if it is the case, may be because of sql transaction page is slow,
you can save your `data-table` in `session or view state` and filter this data-table based upon the selected index. this will stop the hit to sql server.

on other way you can use ajax to get data-table ,this will prevent your full page post back.